# TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy log4j2 not rolling over when new day happens

Tags: log4j2, rollover

I have configured Log4j2 with the following configuration, but TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not working, I am getting new day logs in older day's logs, can you please help. It is rolling over properly with size and it is also creating any number of files since I have specified "nomax" attribute for DefaultRollOverStrategy, only TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy is not working. It writes logs of a day in the previous day's log file. It does create the new log file with the latest date, but some logs have been logged in to the previous day's log. May be getting problem in naming the files properly I do not know.

```
  {
  "Configuration": {
    "Properties": {
      "Property": [
        {
          "name": "application",
          "value": "myapp"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Appenders": {
      "Console": {
        "name": "Console-Appender",
        "target": "SYSTEM_OUT",
        "PatternLayout": {
          "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ${application} %-5level %marker %t %c{5}  %msg%n"
        },
         "ThresholdFilter": { "level": "error" }
      },
      "RollingFile": [
        {
          "name": "File-Appender",
          "fileName":"${sys:log.path}/${application}.log",
          "filePattern":"${sys:log.path}/${application}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log",
          "PatternLayout": {
            "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} ${application} %-5level %marker %t %c{5}  %msg%n"
          },
          "Policies": {
            "TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {"interval":"1", "modulate":"true" },
             "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": { "size": "5 KB" } 
            },
            "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {"fileIndex":"nomax"}   
        }
      ]
    },
    "loggers": {
      "logger":{
        "name": "com.mycompany",
        "level": "${sys:log.level}",
        "AppenderRef": { "ref": "File-Appender"}
      },
      "root": {
        "level": "error",
        "AppenderRef": { "ref": "Console-Appender" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem of not rolling over is coming when there are no logs for a particular day. How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding :

```json
    "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy": {"minSize":"0"}
```

to the policies solved the problem.

From [log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#OnStartup_Triggering_Policy):

> The OnStartupTriggeringPolicy policy causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's start time and the minimum file size is met or exceeded.
>
> OnStartupTriggeringPolicy Parameters:
>
> minSize:  long:   The minimum size the file must have to roll over. A size of zero will cause a roll over no matter what the file size is. The default value is 1, which will prevent rolling over an empty file

Comment: From log4j2 documentation: OnStartup Triggering Policy
The OnStartupTriggeringPolicy policy causes a rollover if the log file is older than the current JVM's start time and the minimum file size is met or exceeded.

OnStartupTriggeringPolicy Parameters
minSize: long: The minimum size the file must have to roll over. A size of zero will cause a roll over no matter what the file size is. The default value is 1, which will prevent rolling over an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [`CronTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/CronTriggeringPolicy.html)? This will trigger a rollover for you every day at 12AM:

```
{"CronTriggeringPolicy": {"schedule": "0 0 0,12 * * ?"}
```

That way, it won't rely on the file pattern and should definitely roll your logs over per your `cron` interval. I also don't know how you determined that the previous days logs were included in the rollover, but make sure your system time is in sync.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, we will give it a try. We checked the log files, with this configuration I have posted, sometimes, for example, today's log is in the previous day's log file. Eventually it is rolling over, I do not know based on what.