# Log4j2: TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy triggering one line too late

Tags: java, log4j2

I've added a simple Appender to my log4j2.xml config to basically log out some prices (in a csv format) via a PRICES marker:

```
<RollingFile name="prices"
         fileName="${log-path}/prices.csv"
         filePattern="${log-path}/prices.csv.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
  <MarkerFilter marker="PRICES" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
  </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

Every day at a certain time (let's say 8pm), the code will log something with the PRICES marker, which should go to this file. It works in general, but there's a strange behavior:

The first line logged does not go into today's file, but instead into yesterday's file.

So it seems to me, that it rolls only after writing the first line. Of course this is slightly annoying, so my question is: How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can solve the issue by including an [`OnStartupTriggeringPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) with a `minSize` attribute equal to `0` ([default is `1`](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/913e87d7747aa8d90b7bd3236c4dca2e3307336a/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/OnStartupTriggeringPolicy.java#L104-L108)) in your `Policies` configuration. Basically it will provide you a way to rotate the logs every time the JVM starts and the minimum indicated file size is met or exceeded:

```xml
<Policies>
  <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0" />
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
</Policies>
```

A similar issue to the one you are faced has been described in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636801/timebasedtriggeringpolicy-log4j2-not-rolling-over-when-new-day-happens).

Comment: Good idea, but unfortunately, this is not an option, since the application will run for days at a time and not be restarted, so the JVM (re)start will not happen every day...

Comment: Thank you very much. I see Florian. I am very sorry that the answer was not helpful.